# for, increment with four zeros

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

```
$second= 3113;
for ($i = 0000; $i < 7000; $i += 100) { 
     $a=$second.$i;// 31130
     ...
}
```

This will output:

```
31130
3113100
3113200
```

What I need:

```
31130000 
31130100 
31130200
```

How do you solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers will always be shown with zeroes trimmed. You can force a certain number of zeroes with [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) like so:

```
$a = $second.sprintf("%04s",$i); // 31130000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead:

```
$second= 3113;
for ($i = 0000; $i < 7000; $i += 100) { 
     $a=$second.($i>0?($i>=1000?$i:"0".$i):"0000");// 3113000
     ...
}
```

This will check if `$i` is greater than 0. If it isn't it will output "0000" instead.

If `$i` is less than 1000, it will add a 0 to the beginning.